# (MAC) Are these commands to be trusted (sudo nano)?

Tags: terminal, sudo, nano

A person asked me to do this:

1. Open the Terminal
2. Enter command `sudo nano /etc/hosts`
3. Hit Enter
4. Enter the password for the Administrator
5. Hit Enter
6. Insert the cursor in a blank line at the end then copy these
   host url and paste there

```
    127.0.0.1  api.wondershare.com  
    127.0.0.1  wondershare.cn.edgesuite.net  
    127.0.0.1  a1737.g.akamai.net  
    127.0.0.1  wondershare.cn.edgesuite.net  
    127.0.0.1  platform.wondershare.com  
    127.0.0.1  macplatform.wondershare.com  
    127.0.0.1  cbs.wondershare.com  
    127.0.0.1  us.wondershare.com  
    127.0.0.1  my.wondershare.com  
    127.0.0.1  pop.wondershare.com
```

Then press:
Ctrl+O -> Enter -> Ctrl+X
Close the terminal

Is this trustable?

Comment: This will have the effect of preventing your computer from accessing any of the named machines, which is probably what you want.  It will do no harm; if you don't like the result you can follow the exact same steps to edit the file and revert some or all of the changes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are probably to be trusted. I depends on whhich effect you want to archieve, which is not stated in the question. What it attemps to though is the following:

1. Start an editor with elevated rights.
2. Open the file `/etc/hosts` which most systems use for DNS lookup.
3. Edit it so that some names point back to your own local computer rather than to so machine on the Internet (effectively blocking these sites).
4. Save

If you do not want to reach those machines then yes, this is safe to do. It used to be quite common on Un*x/linux/BSD and windows platforms as a trivial way to block some adds.

Three notes though:

1. OSX seems to have the host file in a different place. Some googling shows me `/private/etc/hosts/`. This is OXs specific. Make sure that you are editing the right file and that the changes persist after a reboot.
   [Edit] On recent OSX systems `/etc` symlinks to `/private/etc`
2. Alternatively you could use ::1 rather than 127.0.0.1.
3. You might need to tell OSX that something has changed. Without that it might already have cached the real IP for one of these hosts. `dscacheutil -flushcache;sudo killall -HUP mDNSResponder` seems to do that.

Comment: Thank you very much, I issued the commands and nothing is wrong with my system.

Comment: Asking what things to (especially involving sudo) when you do not know it is a good thing. Not sure that it still is the best solution though. These days blocking software has evolved and there are more userfriendly and automatic updates available. If you want to block annoying adds then use an addblocker. If you want more security then use an add blocker. If it is something else then the 'a person' solution might be a good thing and I excuse myself for the long comment.

Comment: @Hennes, regarding note #1, on recent OSX systems, `/etc` symlinks to `/private/etc`

Comment: Ah, good to know. No OSX here (no MAC hardware to run it on), so I have to go with general knowledge and whatever I can google.